# Volley listeners cause memory leak inside fragment

Tags: android, memory-leaks

I see that I've a memory leak reference xRequest who references `ResponseListener` and `ErrorListener`

I'm creating request like this:

```
public void createReq() {
    xRequest = new xRequest(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), .., this);
    xRequest.enqueue();
}
```

I'm canceling Volley request in fragment:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    xRequest.cancel();
}
```

Implementation of `xRequest`:

```
public class xRequest ... {


public xRequest(Context context, ..., Callback callback) {
    super(context, Method.GET, String.format(URL, page), new ResponseListener(callback), new ErrorListener(callback));
}

private static class ResponseListener implements Response.Listener<String> {
    private Callback mCallback;

    public ResponseListener(Callback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {
        try {
            ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            ...
        }
    }
}

private static class ErrorListener implements Response.ErrorListener {
    private Callback mCallback;

    public ErrorListener(Callback callback) {
        this.mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        ..
    }
}

public interface Callback {
    void onSuccess(...);

    void onError(String error);

    void onNetworkError(VolleyError error);
}
}
```

What's the correct way of destroy `xRequest` listener references to avoid memory leaks?

Comment: why do you have those static inner classes?

Comment: I read somewhere, that you should user `static` keyword for inner classes to avoid leaks.